# Main Activity is not assignable android.app.Activity error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-manifest

I'm very new to Android developing. I'm having an issue running my app. I'm trying to get a toast for incoming call notifications by using a BroadcastReceiver.  but I'm getting this error from the manifest *com.sortinousn.Salesforce.calltracker is not assignable to android.app.Activity*.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sortinousn.salesforcecalltracker"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.sortinousn.salesforcecalltracker.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-    permission>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

Context pcontext;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    try {
        // TELEPHONY MANAGER class object to register one listner
        TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        //Create Listner
        MyPhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();

        // Register listener for LISTEN_CALL_STATE
        tmgr.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Phone Receive Error", " " + e);
    }

}

private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        Log.d("MyPhoneListener",state+"   incoming no:"+incomingNumber);

        if (state == 1) {

            String msg = "New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number :     "+incomingNumber;
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(pcontext, msg, duration);
            toast.show();

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you MUST add all the activities in your manifest. If i am not wrong you have not added calltracker activity in your manifest. Do give a go with that

Comment: `MainActivity` is a receiver so, you cannot declare it in `android:name` property of `<activity>` tag

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why you put the `MainActivity` class as an `activity` and a `receiver`...these are not the same.

And as I can see in your code, you haven't any activity, 'cause you extend `BroadcastReceiver` in your MainActivity class...so...just make a real activity by extending another class with `Activity` (or others) and declare this class as an activity in your manifest, just like this : the `Activity` :

```
package fr.zwedge.kingwarrior;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Tell me if I'm wrong for what's above
        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                try {
                    // TELEPHONY MANAGER class object to register one listner
                    TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                    //Create Listner
                    MyPhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();

                   // Register listener for LISTEN_CALL_STATE
                   tmgr.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

               } catch (Exception e) {
                   Log.e("Phone Receive Error", " " + e);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   public /* can't be private here */ class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
      public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
         Log.d("MyPhoneListener",state+"   incoming no:"+incomingNumber);

         if (state == 1) {
            String msg = "New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number :     "+incomingNumber;
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(pcontext, msg, duration);
            toast.show();
         }
      }
  }
```

The `Manifest` :

```
<application android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="King Warrior"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launch">
    <activity android:name=".Main"
        android:label="What you want"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launch">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Hope it helps,
Darkball60.

==================================

Or you can just delete the `<activity />` tag in your manifest, if you don't want any interface for your app.

Answer (score 0):

you can not declare a receiver for an activity, you must create your receiver outside your activity and make a callback this one in your MainActivity.